Many LaTeX packages missing after upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04.1
I upgraded my PC from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04.1. Many LaTeX packages are missing, like a4wide, stmaryrd, fullpage, accents and also (very very annoying !!) tikz and abraces and enumitem. Where are they ?

The upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04.1 is strange. With sudo apt install texlive-full, everything seems to be back to normal. I leave my question which can be useful for other people I think.

The version you have in 22.04 most likely had reference to components that do not exist in 24.04 - e.g. as basic as a new glibc version, probably. Only one thing to do, remove the remains and install anew; done. There may be more similar issues, which is why I always reinstall from a fresh ISO.

I have a list of packages for a fresh install and indeed, other ones like VLC were not installed. Everything is fixed now I hope.
